# Creative senz3d urdf or measurements

Tags: ros, urdf, camera, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Has anyone made a URDF for the [Creative Senz3D](http://hk.creative.com/p/web-cameras/creative-senz3d) or know where to find one? I'm looking for measurements that describe the relationship between different frames of the Creative Senz3D. Its also known as the Softkinetic
DS325V2_M.

Here's an example of a URDF file describing the Kinect's frames of reference:

```
    <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="" rpy="" />
        <parent link="" />
        <child link="camera_link" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="camera_depth_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0 0.018 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="camera_link" />
        <child link="camera_depth_frame" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="camera_depth_optical_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-M_PI/2} 0 ${-M_PI/2}" />
        <parent link="camera_depth_frame" />
        <child link="camera_depth_optical_frame" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="camera_rgb_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0 -0.005 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="camera_link" />
        <child link="camera_rgb_frame" />
    </joint>

    <joint name="camera_rgb_optical_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-M_PI/2} 0 ${-M_PI/2}" />
        <parent link="camera_rgb_frame" />
        <child link="camera_rgb_optical_frame" />
    </joint>
```

Thanks!

Jamie

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190932/creative-senz3d-urdf-or-measurements/) by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2014-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, yes, I'm using the Senz3D mounted on a Turtlebot2. [Here](https://github.com/corot/thorp/blob/master/thorp_bringup/urdf/thorp.urdf.xacro#L112) is my xacro file The camera description is on lines 112 to 167.

The origin of the senz3d_camera_link is the result of camera calibration following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_kinect_arm_calibration?distro=fuerte). And for the other frames, I'm not following the same convention than the kinect, but the final optical frames are the same.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-22**:
Hm, perhaps we should think about setting up some sort of repository for this kind of thing. For the near term: perhaps you could create a Senze3d description package, with an xacro containing just lines 112-167? I see a lot of requests from people looking for this kind of info. Also for other cameras.

**Comment by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on 2014-08-22**:
Awesome! Thanks for answering so fast :)

**Comment by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on 2014-08-22**:
Yeah that's a great idea, it would make it a lot easier if you could just depend on a package and then link to the xacro of the sensor you were using.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-08-22**:
Yep, I use the code from [this repo](https://github.com/ipa320/softkinetic) to integrate the camera on ROS, so that would be the right place to put this. The problem is that repo administrator have not being very active on recent times.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-22**:
I have some contacts there. If you submit something, I'll work with them to get things accepted.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-08-22**:
Ah... sounds good. The repo has a lot of forks, so there is a bunch of people using the camera and so interested on improving it, I asked them to take care of the repo, if they are very busy, but I wonder if they are a company. I'll commit the xacro model as soon as they resolve current PRs.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-22**:
There is not a lot of activity right now as they are mostly on holiday :). Seeing as it is rather orthogonal to the other PRs, I'd suggest just opening one for the model now. Many open PRs shows that the repo is in use, and that people are willing to contribute improvements. If you want, we could coordinate off-list to make sure things are already good-to-go, so the PR becomes a formality.

**Comment by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on 2014-08-22**:
Here's how I'm parametrising the xacro for the camera now if you want to see: https://github.com/jdddog/zoidstein_robot/blob/master/zoidstein_description/urdf/zoidstein_robot.urdf.xacro

**Comment by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on 2014-08-22**:
I'll change the camera xacro link to whatever the offical repo becomes :P

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-08-22**:
did it!  https://github.com/ipa320/softkinetic/pull/24